# React Native Installation

Tags: reactjs, installation, native

I'm trying to install React Native by following instructions on this page : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

but when I want to run my new project I obtain several errors and a log file is created with all what happened during the procedure.
The link to see the log : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Sis1RFrKgiZTFTRWFLUmZpZlk

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to install git, as you log says.

```
2223 error not found: git
2224 error Failed using git.
2224 error This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
2224 error Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
2225 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here you can find how to do it:

[Installing Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)